# Inconsistent notification actions buttons' UI even on same device

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have an app where i'm having some issues with notifications not being consistent on different devices. The notification is used by a foreground service

This is what my notification looks like in my pixel3 api29 emulator

[image]

Because of the issue i'm troubleshooting, I decided to extract the code and put it in a dummy app that would let me simulate the triggering event more easily. However, after doing that and running on the exact same pixel3 api29 emulator, i realized the notification is not even consistent *on the same device*. In the dummy app for a dummy foreground service the notification looks like this

[image]

I can't find what's driving the different look of the action buttons in the two apps. Even the behaviour is different. In the first version, the floating headsup notification stays there forever until i clear it programatically but in the second dummy app the notification clears itself after 6 seconds. I tried using the same theme in both, added the exact same dependency versions thinking that i was pulling different versions of the notification library but nothing, the code to create the notifications is the same in both:

```java
    private Notification createIncomingCallNotification(Intent intent) {
        Intent hangupIntent = new Intent(this, getClass());
        hangupIntent.setAction("hangup");
        PendingIntent hangupPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1244, hangupIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        NotificationCompat.Action hangupAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(0, getActionText(R.string.hangup_button_label, R.color.test1), hangupPendingIntent).build();

        Intent uiIntent = new Intent(this, VideoCallActivity.class);
        uiIntent.putExtras(intent);
        uiIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent fullScreenPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, uiIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Action previewAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(0, getActionText(R.string.preview, R.color.test2), fullScreenPendingIntent).build();

        String caller = "Caller guy";
        Log.v(TAG, "Creating incoming call notification from " + caller);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ChannelIds.INCOMING_CALL_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.incoming_call_notification_title, caller))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_CALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_white_100dp)
                .addAction(hangupAction)
                .addAction(previewAction)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenPendingIntent, true);

        return notificationBuilder.build();
    }

    private Spanned getActionText(@StringRes int stringRes, @ColorRes int colourRes) {
        Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(getText(stringRes));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N_MR1) {
            // This will only work for cases where the Notification.Builder has a fullscreen intent set
            // Notification.Builder that does not have a full screen intent will take the color of the
            // app and the following leads to a no-op.
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getColor(colourRes)), 0, spannable.length(), 0);
        }
        return spannable;
    }
```

Does anyone know what can cause this inconsistency even on the same device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. What changes the headsup notification is this permission in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT"/>
```